# Give an example of a sequence of smooth equicontinuous functions whose derivatives are unbounded

Tags: real-analysis

As the title suggests. I want the function to be from $[a, b]$ to $\mathbb R$. By unbounded derivative, I mean if $f_n$ is a sequence of functions and $M_n$ is the sup norm of $f_n'$ on $[a, b]$, then $\{M_n\}$ is an unbounded sequence of reals. I really have no idea how to do these kind of questions (the ones where you are asked to give an example). Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Is this really what you wanted to ask? If so, consider $f_n=0$.

Comment: oh oops sorry. i mean the derivatives are unbounded.

Comment: What about $f_n(x)=\dfrac{e^{nx}}{n}$?

Comment: What is your definition of smooth on $[a,b]$?

Comment: the usual definition. infinitely differentiable.

Comment: On $(a,b)$ then: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_function What are your conditions at the bounds?

Comment: im not sure what u mean. the question simply asks for the derivatives of the sequence of functions to be unbounded.

Comment: Have you tried the function I proposed?

Comment: @MyUserIsThis i'm trying to show its correctness right now

Comment: @MyUserIsThis although, is it equicontinuous? its definitely smooth and the derivatives are definitely unbounded.

Comment: According to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity They're equicontinuos if they all have the same derivative for the same $x$, isn't that it?

Comment: oh i see. then yes, ur sequence of functions definitely works.

Comment: @AdenDong That's how I interpreted same variation, as I haven't seen a formal definition for that.

Comment: I understand now: when you say derivatives are unbounded, you mean that the sequence of the derivatives is unbounded for the sup norm. Because striclty speaking, the derivatives of the sequence of MyUserIsThis are bounded on $(a,b)$.... Note that the example works only if $b$ is positive. But of course, it is easy to adapt it.

Comment: @MyUserIsThis First, I don't see why you divide your functions by $n$. Then actually, I am not sure that they are equicontinuous. I think the MVT theorem yields a contradiction. Note they do not have the same derivative at the same $x$ like you claim.

Comment: $f_n(x)=\dfrac{e^{nx}}{n}\Longrightarrow (f_n)'=e^x\forall n$ they have the same derivative, although you're right that they're bounded unless $(a,b)=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @MyUserIsThis Sorry but $f_n'(x)=e^{nx}$. This is the chain rule... So yes, the sequence of derivatives is not uniformly bounded if $b>0$. But it is not equicontinuous.

Comment: @MyUserIsThis See here for instance: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080923053026AArcHXN

Comment: derivative is right but they are bounded..

Comment: @HalilDuru Yes, of course, I understood the question like that at first since it is not properly stated. But apparently the OP means: $\sup |f'_n|\longrightarrow +\infty$ as $n\rightarrow +\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $f$ defined on $[0,1]$ by 
$$
f(x)=x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
for $x\neq 0$ and 
$$
f(0)=0.
$$

Then for each $n$, take a smooth function $\phi_n$ such that
$$
\phi_n(x)=0\quad\forall x\in[0,\frac{1}{ n}]\quad \phi_n(x)=1\quad\forall x\in[\frac{2}{n},1]
$$
and 
$$
0\leq \phi_n(x)\leq 1\quad \forall x\in [\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}].
$$
This can be achieved with appropriate modifications of $e^{-1/x^2}$.

Now consider the sequence
$$
f_n=f\phi_n.
$$

I believe this works.

1) Equicontinuity:

First fix $x$ in $(0,1]$ and a small $r>0$. For $n$ large enough, namely $2/n<x-r$, we have $f_n(y)=f(y)$ for all $y\in(x-r,x+r)$.

Take $\epsilon>0$. By continuity of $f$ at $x$ there is $0<\delta<r$ such that 
$$
|f_n(y)-f_n(x)|=|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon \qquad \forall n\geq N=\lfloor\frac{2}{x-r}\rfloor+1.
$$
Now $f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_{N-1}$ are all continuous at $x$ and in finite number, so there exist a common $\delta'>0$ such that $|f_n(y)-f_n(x)|\epsilon$ for these $n$ and all $y\in(x-\delta',x+\delta')$.

It only remains to take the minimum of $\delta$ and $\delta'$ to get what you want and equicontinuity at $x$ follows.

Now take $x=0$. We have $|f_n(y)|\leq y\sin (1/y)\leq y$ for all $y\in[0,1]$ and all $n$. So equicontinuity at $0$ follows.

By compactness of $[0,1]$, we even have uniform equicontinuity.

2) Uniform unboundedness of the derivatives:

Compute $f'(x)$ and check it is unbounded as $x$ approaches $0$.
The claim follows easily.

3) Smoothness is obvious.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit why $f_n$ is equicontinuous at $x \in (0, 1]$? Sorry if this is a stupid question, but it doesn't seem immediately obvious to me.

Comment: Also, I'm having trouble understanding why f_n is smooth because I believe $f'$ has no limit as $x \to 0$.

Comment: @AdenDong Ok, forget the previous comment, I was in a rush and I don't know what I was thinking. I constructed this example precisely to have $\sup|f'_n$ finite for each $n$, but tending to $+\infty$ as $n\rightarrow+\infty$. On $[0,1/n]$, $f_n=0$ so it is smooth as you mean it, with limits of the derivatives at $0$ equal to $0$. On $[1/n,1]$ it is equalt to the smooth $\phi_nf$ which is smooth with bounded derivatives and limits of the derivatives at $1$ exist also, even if they are nonzero. So it does the job. Regarding equicontinuity, I will add a few words. Let me know if it's better.

Comment: @AdenDong You're welcome. Glad it helped.

Comment: A further comment: $f(y) = y\sin(1/y)$ but $f_n(y) = \sin 1$ for $n$ large enough such that $\frac{2}{n} < x - r$. So how are these two equal?

Comment: @AdenDong No. For $n$ like you say, we have $\phi_n(x)=1$, so $\phi_n(x)f(x)=f(x)$. That is $f_n(x)=f(x)$, by definition. Maybe you misunderstood the definition of $f_n$. It is the product of $f$ and $\phi_n$.

Comment: oh i see i see. i thought perhaps you meant function composition. my bad.